# Torch unable to locate HDF5 header file

Tags: hdf5, torch

So, I'm trying to set up the torch-rnn on my mac (Sierra) using [this tutorial](https://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2016/03/25/torch-rnn-mac-install/). I have completed steps 1-6 (basic installation and preprocessing data) but when I try to run the actual training command needed I run into an error:

```
Catons-Mac-mini:torch-rnn catons$ th train.lua -gpu -1 -input_h5 data/datafile.h5 -input_json data/datafile.json
/Users/catons/torch/install/bin/luajit: /Users/catons/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: /Users/catons/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: /Users/catons/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/hdf5/ffi.lua:42: Error: unable to locate HDF5 header file at /usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.10.1/include;/usr/include;/usr/local/opt/szip/include/hdf5.h
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /Users/catons/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'
    train.lua:6: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...tons/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x0105195a10
```

NOTE: I have had to modify the train command due to lack of CUDA support

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling hdf5 using brew, including with the --with-mpi option. Nevertheless, the header file still isn't showing up.

Thanks for any help or advice!

EDIT: OK, so the header file is actually there and I don't think that torch can't locate it due to a problem with permissions as I set the permissions for the file as `-rwxrwxrwx` (which, admittedly, might be overkill).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am running an early 2013 Mac with Sierra.

What worked for me was to use HDF5 1.8 instead of 1.10.1.

```
brew install hdf5@1.8
```

Then update the path in /Users/catons/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/hdf5/init.lua to point to 1.8 instead of 1.10.1.

```
hdf5._config = {
  HDF5_INCLUDE_PATH = "/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5@1.8/1.8.18/include",
  HDF5_LIBRARIES = "/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5@1.8/1.8.18/lib/libhdf5.dylib;/usr/local/opt/szip/lib/libsz.dylib;/usr/lib/libz.dylib;/usr/lib/libdl.dylib;/usr/lib/libm.dylib"
}
```

If you get a "close" error after this, replace line 44 in the ffi.lua file in that same directory with:

```
local process = io.popen("gcc -D '_Nullable=' -E " .. headerPath) -- TODO pass -I
```

Finally, if you're using torch-cl, you'll need to replace the path and line 44 in the torch-cl versions of the config.lua and ffi.lua.